# Wheel spokes complete with spoke-shoe burst through rim

Tags: rims, spokes

Help. All we need is a bike with two wheels that work as they should. 
I've never come across this issue with a bike... ever! Because I cant get any answers from the maker Scott Bikes or the supplier (Start Cycles, Newcastle), I need to do some research. I ask, as you read, please can you consider... 
A. Is spoke+ spokeshoe ingress through wheel rim a common problem with wheels? 
B. Is this a common problem with syncros wheels? 
C. Is the problem acceptable and do we just live with it? 
D. What is the problem? A light child on a particularly heavy mountain-bike or a material too soft to do the job?

My grandson has a Scott Bike (Innovation Technology Design). It came with syncros wheel rims and bought for Christmas 2017 (now 5 months out of warranty).
We noticed a wobble on the rear wheel around a year earlier. The wobble became me extreme and I check the spokes. At least 5 were loose (and without purchase) so I bought a spoke tool to improve the tensioning in advance of service.
When I looked closely, I realized that the real problem was that the problem spokes with spoke shoe (not in 1 place but spread around the wheel) had burst through the rim metal; that makes it impossible to fix. The only solution would be to have a replacement rim.
I asked Scott Cycles distributors to provide a replacement and was advised the bike was out of warranty. I had advised them that there appeared to be a design spec issue with either the Syncros rim material or the spokes with the likelihood that the rim metal is too soft for what is required of it... "not fit for purpose".
I was advised that stock was "fairly low" on the original, (I only need one) the supplier offered a Phillips wheel replacement at around £54.00 + 5.00 delivery to shop (plus fitting charge).
I asked the manufacturer to seriously consider the error of their way... that there are implications as far as I can see. 
1. Question of designed obsolescence and waste
2. Question of child safety both on both and dirt track. 
I next need to pursue this with the CEO of Scott Cycles it appears; the local distributor also are what can be colloquially said to be "a waste of space" and don't appear to understand the seriousness of the issue. 
I can provide a copy of the final word from Scott Cycles. It dwells on the issue of warranty. There has been no injury and no stress on the road... only in dealing with the dealer/ and Scott UK. Perhaps this is acceptable now to the majority of consumers but it shouldn't be. 
Many thanks for your time

Comment: The thing on the rim end of the spoke is called a "nipple".

Comment: Usually when this sort of thing happens it's due to excessive stress on the wheel (such as regularly "bumping" over curbs rather than hopping them), or a failure to maintain an older wheel, to the point that it begins to wobble.  But I do see that Syncros likes to use "straight" spokes, and these are the devil.  Hoity-toity but a devil to maintain, and, lacking flex, more likely to produce the sort of failure you see.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a consumer complaint, not a bike question.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. Very helpful. And yes Adam, in the absence of useful or helpful dealer or manufacturer information it is necessary to do some research. The best way to do this is to ask the cycling community. It is only a consumer complaint because it is a reported product design error that, given the manner in which it has been dealt with, it has now passed beyond the 'last word' of the people who are responsible. Maybe as Adam votes it is safe to have this type of design error go without reporting but when was the search for knowledge and accountability banned?

Comment: I didn't vote to close because there are actually some questions in there, but it definitely needs re-writing to focus on that aspect and less on the general 'rant'

Comment: Accpeted will hve a look at the rant bit.

Comment: Are the spoke holes not reinforced with eyelets? One can also use washers (DT Swiss requires it on some rims).

Comment: Thanks Michael, I am now looking at that. Something like this might make this rim viable. As it stands, 20 miles from home and causing punctures, it's not repairable; the answer cant be pulled from the puncture repair kit but maybe it can with a retrofit washers. Will report back. Surprising that none of the 5 failed spoke-sets around the wheel had caused a puncture over time.

Answer (score 2):

**A. Is spoke+ spokeshoe ingress through wheel rim a common problem with wheels?**

Not a common problem exactly - wheel rims are generally quite robust.  However when they do fail, cracks in the rim around the spoke holes are not at all unheard of.

**B. Is this a common problem with syncros wheels?**

No more so than any other type of wheel in my experience. It's highly likely syncros rims are rebranded offerings from a supplier that provides rims for many brands.

**C. Is the problem acceptable and do we just live with it?**

Disappointing yes, but ultimately acceptable.
Any moving part on a bike can be considered a consumable part that will need to be replaced at some point.  And on mountain bikes in particular this can be even more the case because they are subjected to more extreme conditions.

**D. What is the problem?**

Hard to say, and certainly impossible to prove it's a manufacturing fault.  Possibly built with too much spoke tension to begin with.  Or possibly run into rocks/logs etc at high speed.  Maybe crashed (repeatedly) because that's a natural part of mountain biking - especially when learning.
And then there's any number of things kids do because they are kids (home made jumps, giving friends piggy backs etc) that would certainly not be recommended by the manufacturer.

Comment: Thanks Andy. Yes I would say that kerb behaviour is the most likely cause of this. The damaged nipples are intact of course. The rim proves itself unable to prevent the shoe from passing through. I could see that a slightly larger nipple would prevent the problem because it has a better purchase on the rim. The damaged spokes are not in a single place but spread around the circumference.

Comment: I've certainly lost a wheel to the nipple pulling through the rim before, on a heavily loaded back wheel. It's not a common failure but it does happen

Comment: @ChrisH I had 2 rear wheels fail on me this way (original wheel plus warranty replacement) in under a year (19 months total from the purchase).  Not right at the nipples, though, the entire inside of the rim started to split away from the sidewalls.  Refused another warranty replacement and bought a decent wheel instead, which is still fine after 5 years.  (Admittedly I also stopped riding off kerbs with a full load on the rack...). I figure that sometimes the OEM components aren't that great, at least not on mid-spec or below bikes.

Comment: Thanks ChrisH and DavidW. I'm sorry to hear of your experience. If it were mine, it may have been the end of me. Ive ridden bikes for many years without issue. Perhaps the rim is split as you say. Now warranty is not an issue, I will take it apart asap. On weight; I was not party to the cycle purchase and shocked at the heavy weight at the saddle end. It is a v heavy bike; its an adult bike and the rider has been a relatively light teen. He assures me he's never done backers and carries no bags but kerb behaviour has taken time to be wholly understood.